# Split stdClass/Array returned by Query Builder in Laravel into 2 arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

So im trying to get all the details from all bills, in the bill_details table i have a column to identify the bill this detail belongs to (foreing key), my query look like this:

```
return $this
            ->join('bill_detail as bd'  , 'bills.id'            , '=', 'bd.bill_id')
            ->join('business'           , 'bills.business_id'   , '=', 'business.id')
            ->select('bills.user_id','bd.item','bd.quantity','bd.amount','bd.bill_id','bills.total')
            ->where('bills.user_id', '=', $user)
            ->get();
```

Which returns this stclass or array(formated with php):

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(6) 
        { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["item"]=> string(4) "Coffe" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> string(4) "2.00" ["bill_id"]=> int(1) ["total"]=> string(5) "15.00" }
    [1]=> array(6) 
        { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["item"]=> string(18) "Water" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> string(4) "6.00" ["bill_id"]=> int(1) ["total"]=> string(5) "15.00" } 
    [2]=> array(6)
        { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["item"]=> string(7) "Apple" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["bill_id"]=> int(2) ["total"]=> string(5) "23.00" } 
    [3]=> array(6) 
        { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["item"]=> string(8) "Orange" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> string(4) "4.00" ["bill_id"]=> int(2) ["total"]=> string(5) "23.00" } 
}
```

Is there any optimal way rather than a foreach to split this array into a multi-dimensional array based on the bill_id column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can `collect` it and then group by `bill_id`.

```
$results = $this
    ->join('bill_detail as bd'  , 'bills.id'            , '=', 'bd.bill_id')
    ->join('business'           , 'bills.business_id'   , '=', 'business.id')
    ->select('bills.user_id','bd.item','bd.quantity','bd.amount','bd.bill_id','bills.total')
    ->where('bills.user_id', '=', $user)
    ->get();

return collect($results)->groupBy('bill_id');
```

Comment: Thats it, much apreciated @user3158900 !